# Creating large matrices from sub blocks

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

I am trying to generate a matrix from square blocks. Effectively, I have three blocks, call them $A_{diag}$, $A_{up}$, $A_{down}$, and a block of zeroes, which I'll just call $0$. I have some integer $L$ such that if $L=1$ then I am generating the matrix

$$M = \begin{pmatrix} A_{diag} \end{pmatrix}$$

If $L=2$ then I should generate

$$M = \begin{pmatrix} A_{diag} & A_{up} \\ A_{down} & A_{diag} \end{pmatrix}$$

If $L=3$ then

$$M = \begin{pmatrix} A_{diag} & A_{up} & 0 \\ A_{down} & A_{diag} & A_{up} \\ 0 & A_{down} & A_{diag} \end{pmatrix}$$

If $L=4$ then

$$M = \begin{pmatrix} A_{diag} & A_{up} & 0  & 0\\ A_{down} & A_{diag} & A_{up} 
& 0 \\ 0 & A_{down} & A_{diag} & A_{up} \\ 0 & 0 & A_{down} & A_{diag}\end{pmatrix}$$

and so forth. I suspect this is relatively simple, I found other questions which were similar but more complicated and specific. Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: [Something like `SparseArray` with `Band`?](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html) (See 1st example in the Basic Examples section.)

Comment: Ah that would also work, thanks, I didn't know about `Band`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the other posted methods work, this is the one I wound up using, based on corey979's suggestion:

```
If[L == 1,
  A[r_] := Adiag[r],
  mup   = SparseArray[Band[{1, 2}] -> 1, {L, L}];
  mdown = SparseArray[Band[{2, 1}] -> 1, {L, L}];
  mdiag = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, {L, L}];
  A[r_] :=
    KroneckerProduct[mup  ,   Aup[r]] + 
    KroneckerProduct[mdown, Adown[r]] + 
    KroneckerProduct[mdiag, Adiag[r]];
  ];
```

It has the advantage of using `SparseArray`'s, which is desirable if `L` is large. One can always use `Normal` to convert the `SparseArray`'s into regular matrices for small `L`. For my application for example I found that using normal matrices was faster for `L < 3` but using `SparseArray`'s was faster for `L > 3`, with both being equally fast for `L = 3`.

Comment: Wow, this one is really fast. Respect.

Comment: For your `mdiag`, I would instead use `IdentityMatrix[L, SparseArray]`.

Comment: Thanks, I don't notice much change in speed but it certainly makes more sense.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`ArrayFlatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten) and [`DiagonalMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiagonalMatrix):

```
mat[diag_, up_, down_, n_] := ArrayFlatten @ Block[{Identity},
    DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[Identity[diag], n]]+
    DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[Identity[up], n-1], 1]+
    DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[Identity[down], n-1], -1]
]
```

I used a blocked [`Identity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Identity) head so that [`DiagonalMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiagonalMatrix) didn't complain.

Example:

```
mat[Array[a, {2,2}], Array[b, {2,2}], Array[c, {2,2}], 3] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  a(1,1) & a(1,2) & b(1,1) & b(1,2) & 0 & 0 \\
>  a(2,1) & a(2,2) & b(2,1) & b(2,2) & 0 & 0 \\
>  c(1,1) & c(1,2) & a(1,1) & a(1,2) & b(1,1) & b(1,2) \\
>  c(2,1) & c(2,2) & a(2,1) & a(2,2) & b(2,1) & b(2,2) \\
>  0 & 0 & c(1,1) & c(1,2) & a(1,1) & a(1,2) \\
>  0 & 0 & c(2,1) & c(2,2) & a(2,1) & a(2,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Thanks, the only downside to this is it doesn't work when `n=1`

Comment: I simply added `If[n>1, (your code) , Adiag]` which works perfectly it seems

Answer (score 4):

The `` "SparseArray`" `` context contains many hidden gems, for example this one:

```
SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[{
   Band[{1, 1}] -> SparseArray@Array[a, {2, 2}],
   Band[{1, 2}] -> SparseArray@Array[b, {2, 2}],
   Band[{2, 1}] -> SparseArray@Array[c, {2, 2}]
   }, {3, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left( \begin{array}{cccccc}  a(1,1) & a(1,2) & b(1,1) & b(1,2) & 0
> & 0 \\  a(2,1) & a(2,2) & b(2,1) & b(2,2) & 0 & 0 \\  c(1,1) & c(1,2)
> & a(1,1) & a(1,2) & b(1,1) & b(1,2) \\  c(2,1) & c(2,2) & a(2,1) &
> a(2,2) & b(2,1) & b(2,2) \\  0 & 0 & c(1,1) & c(1,2) & a(1,1) & a(1,2)
> \\  0 & 0 & c(2,1) & c(2,2) & a(2,1) & a(2,2) \\ \end{array} \right)$$

It's not very efficient, though...

Answer (score 2):

There it is,

```
M[n_] := Adiag IdentityMatrix[n] + 
Table[Aup KroneckerDelta[i + 1, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}] + 
Table[Adown KroneckerDelta[i - 1, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];

MatrixForm[M[3]]
```

to elaborate more, you can have Aup[i, j] and Adown[i, j] and Adiag[i, i].