# Is there a more natural way to create matrix from consituitve blocks?

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix that I'd like to augment with identity:

```
b = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1, -1}}.DiagonalMatrix[{1, -1, -1, -1}];
i = DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}];
b // MatrixForm
i // MatrixForm
```

i.e.:

[image: blocks]

I was able to combine these compatible block matrixes with the following mess:

```
xx = Flatten[{b, i} // Transpose , 2];
yy = {xx[[1 ;; 6]], xx[[7 ;; 12]]} ;
yy // MatrixForm
```

[image: augmented]

This seems very perverse.  I found ArrayFlatten mentioned in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164897/10, which looked promising, but had trouble adapting it to my simple case.

How would construction of a matrix from blocks such as these be done in a less horrific fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Join[b, i, 2]

ArrayFlatten[{{b, i}}]

ArrayPad[b, {{0}, {0, 2}}, i]

MapThread[Join, {b, i}]
```

all give

> ```
>  {{1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1}}
> ```

```
 TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ %
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Note:** You can use `IdentityMatrix[2]` for `i`:

```
i == IdentityMatrix[2]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: Thanks.  I needed an extra set of braces in my ArrayFlatten attempt!